# Convert Larger CIDR (eg /16) to list of /24

Tags: ip, converters, cidr

I have a hardware firewall that won't accept CIDR entries larger than /24.  I often need to block larger ranges (eg /17 or /20) but typing out all those /24 CIDRs is not practical.

I'm hoping someone has a way to do this - either with an online tool, something I can install on a Linux server, something I can install on a Windows computer, or even an Excel trick if that's possible. I'm desperate.

Example:

I want to enter this: 192.168.0.0/17

And get back a result like this:

192.168.0.0/24

192.168.1.0/24

192.168.2.0/24

192.168.3.0/24

192.168.4.0/24

... all the way to ...

192.168.127.0/24

This tool sort of does what I want, but has so much extra data in the results that it would be just as much work to clean it up as it is to enter each /24 manually.

http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.0.0&mask1=17&mask2=24

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a bit of Java, then the following code, using the [IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) (Disclaimer: I am the project manager) handles this.  If you do not know Java programming, then you'd need to start with a crash course in Java.

```java
IPAddress addr = new IPAddressString("192.168.0.0/17").getAddress();
IPAddress shifted = addr.adjustPrefixLength(7, false);
Iterator<? extends IPAddress> iterator = shifted.prefixBlockIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.0/24
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/24
192.168.3.0/24
...
192.168.125.0/24
192.168.126.0/24
192.168.127.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

Python version.

```py
import ipaddress

# +network+ str or Network object
# +prefix+ int number of bits desired in result Networks.
# Returns a flat list of Networks up to prefixlen.
#
# Ex explode_to('192.168.0.0/22', 24)
# => [IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24'), IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')]
def explode_to(network, prefixlen=24):
    if isinstance(network, str):
        network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
    if network.prefixlen == prefixlen:
        return [network];
    subnets = [explode_to(sub, prefixlen) for sub in network.subnets()]
    return [nwk for sublist in subnets for nwk in sublist] # flatten
```

Comment: I solved the issue with excel long ago, but this solution looks interesting - thanks!

Comment: glad to help.  I had the same issue and thought I would post the solution in case anyone else needed it.